# matching query does not exist django heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

i have deployed my app to heroku..

But when i try to go to the page, i get this error from log:

```
apps.adminview.models.Templates.DoesNotExist: Templates matching query does not exist.
```

This is from my adminview models, as you can see it is created correctly:

```
...
class Templates(models.Model):
    description     = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    template_name   = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    isSelected      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    temp_selected   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    width_field      = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    height_field     = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    image_path      = models.ImageField(
                                        width_field="width_field", 
                                        height_field="height_field"
                                    )
    def __str__(self):
        return "("+str(self.id)+") " + self.template_name
```

Anyone could help me with this? Thank you!.

By the way, this is from my settings.py if you need it:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.myuser',
    'apps.contact',
    'apps.cart',
    'apps.adminview',
    'apps.article',
    'apps.factura',
    'apps.notfound',
    'qr_code',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'weMarket.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'apps.adminview.context_processor.enterprise_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: is it work fine in local machine?

Comment: Yes it is working fine :/